# Is there a way to generate a composer lock file from a symfony 2.0.x project?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a symfony 2.0.x project and I want to use composer to install new bundles.
The probem is it will update the framework, the orm and all the vendor directory..

I know I need a composer.lock, but is there a way to quickly generate the lock file?
Else, how can I make it manually? Where can I find the exact commit or version for my installed 3rd party bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the 2.0 version of the *Symfony Standard Edition* and create a `composer.json` file which requires at least these dependencies: (the first 4 are required by the Symfony2 framework and the last one requires the Symfony2 framework 2.0)

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": ">=1.1,<2.0-dev",
        "doctrine/common": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "4.2.*",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0,<1.3-dev",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.0.x"
    }
}
```

You can find this information on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony), open the `2.0.x-dev` version block and read what is required and what is recommend.