# How to add simple-html-dom composer package in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Simple-html-dom is listed in [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/shark/simple_html_dom) how it should be included in symfony2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Symfony2.1 you can use Composer to manage dependencies/packages, if you have Symfony2.0 you should tweak the Symfony Standard Edition to use Composer, more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457618/1149495).

## Method 1

#### 1. Add the package to `composer.json`

Add the following in the `src/composer.json` file:

```
{
    ...,
    require: {
        ...,
        'shark/simple_html_dom': 'dev-master'
    }
}
```

#### 2. Update (install) package

Run the following command:

```
$ php composer.phar update shark/simple_html_dom
```

#### 3. Use it where you want

## Method 2

### 1. Use the `composer require` shortcut command

Run the following command:

```
$ php composer.phar require -n shark/simple_html_dom:dev-master
```

### 2. Use it where you want